# ANdroid - Two Receive Share Intent for Mime Type Image

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying have two diff activities (say A & B)  show up in share menu when someone sends image via sending `android.intent.action.SEND`. A & B have separate function and different label (which should show in the share menu).

The expected behaviour is like twitter: You can share image via Tweet or DM.

How can I do this?

I have already tried creating two intent filters, one each for A & B in the manifest.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But there can be only one default. It does show two option for my app, but the options are wrongly labeled: Meaning the label which should have been for Activity B open Activity A.

Update 1: More Code

```
    <activity
        android:name=".A"
        android:label="This is A" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        
        <activity
        android:name=".B"
        android:label="This is B" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: "but they are wrongly labelled" -- you can put an `android:label` on the `<intent-filter>` to override the default label for the activity. "second option doesn't work" -- we cannot help you with that, as you have not provided a [mcve], which in this case would include the code that "doesn't work" and an explanation of what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Already tried label. And It is wrongly labeled: Meaning the label which should have been for Activity B open Activity A. That is what I meant by "it doesn't work"

Comment: Also, as for the code, I have given you what I did to Manifest.xml . I have added those lines to Manifest.xml in the <activity ..></activity> (for both acitvity A & B). It looks minimal and complete to me.

Comment: You claim to have two activities. Your posted code has one `<intent-filter>`, not attached to any `<activity>`. You say that your problem is with labels, yet your posted snippet has no labels. What you have posted is minimal. It is far from complete. I suggest that you edit your question and post the entire manifest.

Comment: @k3b Please see updated questions. Yes it does show two labels.